# How to add custom directory in URL for app hosted locally on IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, salesforce

I have the following situation for testing purposes my app is hosted on IIS on my machine and when I direct the physical path to the solution folder not the direct folder of the project when I try to access the .aspx file of the site I get the following error:

[image]

The URL (it uses https protocol) is as it should be:

> localhost:159/**SalesforceV5RapidSearch**/RapidSearch.aspx?

The bolded folder must be there because on the staging server the URL is generated automatically and I have to make it work locally with this url. To the core of the problem when I direct the physical path to the project folder everything works and the Urls is `localhost:159/RapidSearch.aspx?` the thing is I need that path to be the same as the above URL.

The given error is because the `<authentication>` element can be set only in the global `web.config` not in any of the subfolders and when I direct the path to the directory of the solution the `web.config` used is in a subfolder. Even if I put the project in two folders to make the URL the same it returns the same error because the `web.config` is again in a subfolder and the IIS does not recognize it as global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution it was to add a web application to the hosted web site in IIS which application leads to the directory in that way the URL is as it should be localhost:159/SalesforceV5RapidSearch/RapidSearch.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed all the required authentication features of the IIS server and have actually published the website in the IIS.

Comment: I have all the required features installed